# How to control pathing when executing a string command using bash -c?

Tags: bash, path, command

Background, I am trying to use a Python library that spawns a subprocess using arguments `["bash", "-c", "python someScript.py"]`. What's happening is Python 2.6 is executed, but I want python2.7 instead. Python 2.6 is in `/usr/bin/` and Python 2.7 is in `/usr/local/bin`

If I say `python -V` and `type python` I get:

`Python 2.7.10` and `python is aliased to /usr/local/bin/python2.7`

(Note, I have set up this alias in my `.bashrc` file: `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7`)

However, if I invoke `bash -c "type python"` I get:

`python is /usr/bin/python`

Both `echo $PATH` and `bash -c "echo $PATH"` output the same path:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib`

Note, I tried to put `/usr/local/bin` first when I export PATH in my .bashrc.

So my question is, what is controlling the pathing (in this case to Python) when I execute a string command using `bash -c` ? Specifically, how do I get `bash -c "python"` to use Python 2.7? Edit: The arguments `["bash", "-c", "python someScript.py"]` are hard-coded in the library, and I'd rather not have to modify the library source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while doing `bash -c '....'`, you are spawning a non-interactive (and non-login) session of `bash`, which will not `source` any runtime configuration file e.g. `~/.bashrc`.

As you have defined the `alias` in `~/.bashrc`, you can use the `-i` option so that `bash` can simulate the interactive environment and hence `source` the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
bash -ic '....'
```

Now the `alias` should be available.

**Example:**

```
$ alias l
alias l='ls'

$ bash -c 'l'
bash: l: command not found

$ bash -ic 'l'
bar  foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path to the command. `bash -c /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: Let me clarify that the subprocess arguments `["bash", "-c", "python someScript.py"]` are hard-coded in the library. I'd like to find a solution that doesn't require modifying the library code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your .bashrc is not sourced in a non-interactive shell such as this - try putting the PATH setting into your .profile file, which will also work for some other shells (or .bash_profile if you only want to set it for bash).